# Interaction.Behaviors in Windows 10 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I'm experimenting with using Interaction.Behaviors in XAML to bind events to my controller like so,

```
<GridView x:Name="mygrid" >
    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding Controller.Test}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mygrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
</GridView>
```

This works perfectly except... Visual Studio 2015 shows the following errors,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The name "EventTriggerBehavior" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core".   MVC C:\Prototype\MVC\MVC\MainPage.xaml  19  
Error       The name "InvokeCommandAction" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core".    MVC C:\Prototype\MVC\MVC\MainPage.xaml  20  
Error       The name "Interaction" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity".    MVC C:\Prototype\MVC\MVC\MainPage.xaml  18
```

This has caused the designer to break, so even though the code works, the designer doesn't.  Any ideas?

My includes are...

```
xmlns:interact="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:interactcore="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

And just to clarify, I included the behaviors SDK via the "Add Reference..." dialog.

Comment: I have the same behavior in VS 2015 Enterprise

Comment: Noticed that your tag is windows-10-universal, and VS is 2012, are you developing an UWP app? When developing UWP app, you must have vs2015, and windows 10 OS. And behaviors SDK (XAML) version 12.0 is for Windows 8.1, for UWP is [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors).

Comment: Sorry that's a typo 2015.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that other library.

Comment: Excellent that worked thanks, so just to clariify, I removed the Behaviors SDK which isn't supported for Windows 10 Universal Apps, and added the new one via the package manager console using 'PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed'

Comment: @Nick, Good to know that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer that worked for me were the comments made by Grace Feng in the question and confirmed by Nick.

That is when doing Windows 10 Universal apps use the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed nuget package and remove the Behaviors SDK (XAML) package